# Stop inactive Bluemix apps

Tags: ibm-cloud

We want to use a shared Bluemix org which contains a number of demo apps. Is there a way of detecting, which apps haven't been used (e.g few http requests) in order to stop inactive apps?

Comment: you can take a look at some of the monitoring services Bluemix offers and bind them to your apps. This can reveal data such as how much traffic your apps are getting and axe the ones no one is using. https://console.bluemix.net/catalog under the DevOps category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These cloud foundry [docs](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/streaming-logs.html#rtr) state the following:

> The Router emits RTR logs when it routes HTTP requests to the app. Router messages include the app name followed by a Router timestamp and then selections from the HTTP request.

You should get an idea of how many requests your apps are receiving by looking for RTR log entries.

Manually, you could check the console logs using the `cf logs ..` command, or by visiting the log page in the Bluemix console.

You could automate the check using the cloud foundry tools or using the cloud foundry apis to parse the applications logs.

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/streaming-logs.html#rtr